# For loops for ggplot2 not returning y axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot multiple y values vs a single x value. I want the graphs to be in seperate figures. The following code is working to generate the graphs, but the y axes are labeled "taxonomy_metadata_combined_p21[,i]" and I want them to have the same labels as the column titles. I have tried multiple different things but how can I change the y axes label?

```
for(i in 2:ncol(taxonomy_metadata_combined_p21)) {                              
  print(ggplot(taxonomy_metadata_combined_p21, aes(x = Txt_Sex, y = taxonomy_metadata_combined_p21[ , i])) +
          geom_boxplot())+
    ylab(colnames(taxonomy_metadata_combined_p21)[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ylab()` was added after the `print()` function. If you print after adding `ylab()` it should work.

As a sidenote; it is not recommended to use `y = taxonomy_metadata_combined_p21[ , i]` as an aesthetic. The ggplot2 authors instead recommend to use the `.data` pronoun if the column name is known.

Reprex with built-in data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- rev(iris)

for (i in 2:ncol(df)) {
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Species, y = .data[[colnames(df)[i]]])) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    ylab(colnames(df)[i])
  print(p)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. The only problem I have left now is that my y labels are very very long (>100 characters) and they are getting cut off on my y axis. I edited the code as follows:

Comment: You might use `ylab(stringr::str_wrap(colnames(df)[i], ...)` to wrap your strings.

Comment: Adding this line did not work: ylab(stringr::str_wrap(colnames(taxonomy_metadata_combined_p21)[i], width = 30))